# Is there a way to combine pack() with place()? - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The lines with the "#" is where I am facing the problem. Wrapper1.pack() does the job of placing the scroll bar inside the LabelFrame while Wrapper1.place() puts it where I want it and sizes it how I want it but doesn't place the scrollbar inside the LabelFrame (I showed the full code below).

Essentially, I want to combine pack() with place() to get my desired results. How do I do it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

wrapper1 = LabelFrame(root)

mycanvas = Canvas(wrapper1)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand="yes")

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical", command=mycanvas.yview )
yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")

mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
mycanvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion = mycanvas.bbox('all')))

myframe = Frame(mycanvas)
mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="nw")


# wrapper1.pack(side = RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10) 
# wrapper1.place(x=680,y=50,height=480,width=270)


for i in range(200):
    Button(myframe, text="My Button - "+str(i)).pack()

root.geometry("960x540")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("My Scroller")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are going to `pack` your widgets in the `wrapper1` frame and you don't want it in the center then add `wrapper1.pack(expand=True, fill="both"`)` your `frame` has to be told to grow as well, not just the widgets inside.

Comment: Use `pack` or `grid` geometry manager, they are MUCH easier to use for laying out a GUI. I would recommend [reading this](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-pack/).  Understanding how the `packer` behaves is key to achieving desired results.

Comment: wrapper1.place(x=5,y=5,height=480,width=270) Or wrapper1.pack(side =LEFT, fill="both", expand="yes")